# VIM and Notepad++ show different text

Tags: vim, notepad++

I am editing C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\DotNetTypes.format.ps1xml

I have -not- changed this file in any way. I am only opening in each editor.

This is a read-only file supplied with PowerShell 5.0.10586.117.

I am running Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise SP1 [Version 6.1.7601]. This does not appear to happen using the same version of VIM on Windows 10.

Here is what VIM 8.0.69 shows.

```
468                     <TableColumnHeader>
469                         <Width>6</Width>
470                         <Alignment>right</Alignment>
471                     </TableColumnHeader>
472                     <TableColumnHeader />
473                 </TableHeaders>
474                 <TableRowEntries>
475                     <TableRowEntry>
476                         <TableColumnItems>
```

VIM 8.0.596 built for Cygwin shows this.

```
 468                     <TableColumnHeader>
 469                         <Width>6</Width>
 470                         <Alignment>right</Alignment>
 471                     </TableColumnHeader>
 472                     <TableColumnHeader>
 473                         <Width>3</Width>
 474                         <Alignment>right</Alignment>
 475                     </TableColumnHeader>
 476                     <TableColumnHeader />
 477                 </TableHeaders>
 478                 <TableRowEntries>
 479                     <TableRowEntry>
```

This is what Notepad++ 7.4 shows.

[image: Notepad++ shows]

This is what NOTEPAD.EXE shows.
[image]

Lines 472 through 475 in Notepad++ do not appear in VIM.

I have seen other discrepancies. Why is this happening? Which editor can I trust?

Comment: I imagine the file has been edited between when you opened it in one editor and when you opened it in the other.

Comment: The file has not been edited between opening in the editors. This is a read-only file that is part of PowerShell

Comment: Notepad, Notepad++, and Vim all show [the same content](http://i.imgur.com/Jttg5H9.png), here: the one on the top. It looks like *you* edited that file in NP++.

Comment: I can't believe that, but who knows: Please check if a plugin "hides" some parts of the file, just start vim using the parameter `-u NORC` (vimrc will be sourced but no plugins will be loaded) or with `- u NONE` (neither vimrc nor plugins will be loaded).

Comment: @Habi - It is hard for me to believe as well. I tried with `-u NORC` and with `-u NONE`. Same result. I note that VIM shows there is a signature at the end of the file while Notepad++, Notepad, XML Editor 2007, do not.

Comment: Could you please make a copy of the file and rename it and try again? The file is part of the system, who knows what is done to that file in the background...

Comment: I will try making a copy. The result is consistent over several days. I don't think this is a background process issue.

Answer (score 0):

Notepad has by default text wrap. I Saw this also in other text editors, such as Beyond-Compare which doesn't even have text-wrap, yet it does have limit line-length of 4096. For xml files that have sometimes **very** long lines, I saw a difference which was also hard to explain, but there you go - a text wrap or line-length limitation